# Mathematica Moderator Business Cards

Tags: discussion

A long long time ago, we printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place.

If you're a mathematica.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own Mathematica Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out to your fellow Mathematica users during local meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: mathematica.stackexchange.com moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/email/phone are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL, etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: Heh heh, bring back the five-point logo! Seriously though, it's a nice idea, though I'm not sure I'd ever use them given my semi-pseudonymous presence here.

Comment: @rm-rf Oh yeah. We'll update that for the actual cards. :)

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Verbeia... while they're nice and shiny (and I've heard good things about their quality from other mods), I don't think I'd need or use these cards.

Comment: btw, I personally think that any top user (for suitable definitions of top) should be able to get such cards to handout at conferences/their workplace/departments/etc.  I know it's probably going to be cost prohibitive to customize for everyone, but perhaps a community version (like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/miYd6.png)?) or customizing only for those attending conferences/etc can be done?

Comment: @rm-rf It still gets a bit costly for us to make and ship these to anyone who might attend a conference, but we have done similar things in the past. Might be worth making that a part of our conference sponsorship process... I'll see if it's feasible.

Comment: Do we have any moderator who (supposedly) uses his/her real name? Maybe pseudonymous or even anonymous incognito cards should be crafted. But that of course would render the whole thing pointless :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar The mods are listed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). All have pseudonyms and just one has a link to any relevant external information. This is certainly well within standard stackexchange practice, but does pose an interesting challenge. Ultimately, though, perhaps an anonymous mod (or any user) would be more comfortable with conference-goer level users knowing their true identities, as opposed to drive bys.

Comment: We can put any name or pseudonym on the cards. Of course, once you hand one out, whoever you give it to will *probably* know who you are anyway.

Comment: @rm-rf You don't have an email set in your profile (which you should ideally change - we need to be able to contact you as a moderator), so just let me know if you change your mind and would like to get a set of these cards.

Comment: @AnnaLear His email address is in the box on the top right of his profile. It's encoded with Mathematica, though :-)

Comment: @Anna It's not there because I don't like getting automated emails for bounty ending/chat cast and other mundane things (some are probably not automated anyway since the bcc has been bungled up in the past) and I prefer to look and read at my own time and pace (and I do). Nevertheless, SE does have my email, since I recently received a moderator newsletter from Grace, received swag mail from you twice in the past, mail from Aarthi, etc. As Sjoerd said, it can also be unencoded from my profile with Mathematica :) So feel free to use that email to contact me anytime... just not by a bot.